# Why does only the first DropDown gets populated when generating DropDown Dynamically with Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to create a DataEntry Grid/table like structure in which user appends new row on button click . The row will have TextBoxes, DropDown, Calendar Control. All of this is supposed to be done on client side. So far I have this and as you can see I am trying to fill DropDownusing var data object (which is working for just first dropdown at the moment).. 
If I am able to fill all DropDowns with the hardcoded `var data` I can try to fetch the data from DataBase using webmethod but first I should atleast be able to fill all DropDowns with hardcoded values first to go beyond it.

**CODE**

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id="field">
    <tr>
        <td>Alternatif <span class='num'>1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><select id="myDropDownLisTId"> <input type="text" id="datepicker"></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteField">Delete Field</button>

<script id="template" type="text/template">
<tr>
    <td class="number">Alternatif</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
     <td><select id="myDropDownLisTId"> <input type="text" id="datepicker"></td>

</tr>
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#addField").click(function (event) {
             $($("#template").html()).appendTo($("#field tbody")).show("slow");
             if ($("td").hasClass("number")) {
                 var i = parseInt($(".num:last").text()) + 1;
                 $($("<span class='num'> " + i + " </span>")).appendTo($(".number")).closest("td").removeClass('number');
             }
             event.preventDefault();
         });

         $("#deleteField").click(function (event) {
             var lengthRow = $("#field tbody tr").length;
             if (lengthRow > 1)
                 $("#field tbody tr:last").remove();
             event.preventDefault();
         });



     var data = [
    { id: '0', name: 'test 0' },
    { id: '1', name: 'test 1' },
    { id: '2', name: 'test 2' },
    { id: '3', name: 'test 3' },
    { id: '4', name: 'test 4' },
];


     for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

         $("#myDropDownLisTId").append(
        $('<option />', {
            'value': data[i].id,
            'name': data[i].name,
            'text': data[i].name
        })
                );

     }
});
    </script>
```

**FIDDLE (update)**

http://jsfiddle.net/FSGbh/5/

Comment: INPUT cannot be child of SELECT element. Check your console, any error?

Comment: So ya, you have duplicate IDs and btw your HTML markup is invalid, second SELECT is even not closed

Comment: I've made required changes in HTML as well in fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that you have same Id twice in your code i.e. `myDropDownLisTId`.

To make it working I've just changed the Id to class, and it is loading the data in second dropdown as well.

**HTML**

```
<table id="field">
    <tr>
        <td>Alternatif <span class='num'>1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="myDropDownLisTId"> <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteField">Delete Field</button>
<tr>
    <td class="number">Alternatif</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><select class="myDropDownLisTId" /> <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#addField").click(function (event) {
             $($("#template").html()).appendTo($("#field tbody")).show("slow");
             if ($("td").hasClass("number")) {
                 var i = parseInt($(".num:last").text()) + 1;
                 $($("<span class='num'> " + i + " </span>")).appendTo($(".number")).closest("td").removeClass('number');
             }
             event.preventDefault();
         });

         $("#deleteField").click(function (event) {
             var lengthRow = $("#field tbody tr").length;
             if (lengthRow > 1)
                 $("#field tbody tr:last").remove();
             event.preventDefault();
         });



     var data = [
    { id: '0', name: 'test 0' },
    { id: '1', name: 'test 1' },
    { id: '2', name: 'test 2' },
    { id: '3', name: 'test 3' },
    { id: '4', name: 'test 4' },
];


     for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

         $(".myDropDownLisTId").last().append(
        $('<option />', {
            'value': data[i].id,
            'name': data[i].name,
            'text': data[i].name
        })
                );

     }
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/)**

**-----
EDIT
-----**

I've updated the answer based on discussion with the user. I've done some changes in code.

**HTML**

```
<table id="field">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Alternatif <span class='num'>1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="myDropDownLisTId"> <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></select></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteField">Delete Field</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
             filldd();

            var rowstring = "<tr><td class='number'>Alternatif</td><td><input type='text'/></td><td><select class='myDropDownLisTId'/><input type='text' id='datepicker'/></td></tr>";
             $("#addField").click(function (event) {
             $("#field tbody").append(rowstring);
             filldd();
             if ($("td").hasClass("number")) {
                 var i = parseInt($(".num:last").text()) + 1;
                 $($("<span class='num'> " + i + " </span>")).appendTo($(".number")).closest("td").removeClass('number');
             }
             event.preventDefault();
         });

         $("#deleteField").click(function (event) {
             var lengthRow = $("#field tbody tr").length;
             if (lengthRow > 1)
                 $("#field tbody tr:last").remove();
             event.preventDefault();
         });
});

 function filldd(){
    var data = [
    { id: '0', name: 'test 0' },
    { id: '1', name: 'test 1' },
    { id: '2', name: 'test 2' },
    { id: '3', name: 'test 3' },
    { id: '4', name: 'test 4' },
];

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         $(".myDropDownLisTId").append(
            $('<option />', {
                'value': data[i].id,
                'name': data[i].name,
                'text': data[i].name
            })
         );
     }
         }
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/2/)**

Comment: This is so not what I want. I am adding row dynamically on button click.

Comment: Dear this answer is in response to your question title. You've clearly mentioned that second dropdown is not being generated. You haven't mentioned anywhere that you are having a problem with adding a row dynamically.

Comment: I do not have a problem generating row. I am able to generate rows without any problem except that only first dropdown gets filled. rest of the row's dropdown do not get filled. But they do get generated.

Comment: @Arbaaz, this answer is correct. The reason that it's not working is because you are using an ID, which is going to call the same element, every time.

Comment: @Metagrapher, at.arbaaz I've done changes which will solve both the problem.

Comment: @ITppl actually, on second look, no...not quite there. Right now you've got a whole array jquery objects. It will likely just pick the first one and append to that still. Have you tried this in a fiddle?

Comment: @Metagrapher : I am not getting your comment dear. Please describe briefly.

Comment: Your code is still calling `$(".myDropDownLisTId").append(...` which is itself a multi selector...if there are multiple elements with that class, it will grab all of them. jQuery will grab the first of that group and so you're still just appending to the first element with the class name.

Comment: I admit though, it is a problem to have the id multiple times.

Comment: @Metagrapher If I am not missing than It would get all the elements with that class name, not first element.

Comment: @Metagrapher how do I fix this?

Comment: @Arbaaz : You don't need to fix it, It'll work fine. It will get all the elements which have that class.

Comment: please check the live demo again .. http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/1/ 
add 3-4 rows and then take a look at the items of first row's dropdown

Comment: @Metagrapher : check this simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HskVz/, here it changes color of all the divs with colorthis class not only first div.

Comment: can you guys take a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530612/how-to-dynamically-generate-calendar-control-using-jquery