# How to Dynamically generate Calendar Control using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am generating rows with dynamically on button click using Jquery.

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/2/

The problem now is that I want to add DatePicker to it but I cant because it works with id and not with class.

**code:**

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <link type="text/css" href="../demoengine/demoengine.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../demoengine/demoengine.js" async defer></script>
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker: Parse and Format Dates</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>
      $(function () {
          $(".datepicker").datepicker({
              dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
              onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                  var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText, inst.settings);
                  var dateText1 = $.datepicker.formatDate("D, d M yy", date, inst.settings);
                  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
                  var dateText2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("D, d M yy", date, inst.settings);
                  $("#dateoutput").html("Chosen date is <b>" + dateText1 + "</b>; chosen date + 7 days yields <b>" + dateText2 + "</b>");
              }
          });
      });
  </script>

<table id="field">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Alternatif <span class='num'>1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="myDropDownLisTId"> <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker" /></select></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteField">Delete Field</button>
```

**JS**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         filldd();

         var rowstring = "<tr><td class='number'>Alternatif</td><td><input type='text'/></td><td><select class='myDropDownLisTId'/><input type='text' class='datepicker'/></td></tr>";
         $("#addField").click(function (event) {
             $("#field tbody").append(rowstring);
             filldd();
             if ($("td").hasClass("number")) {
                 var i = parseInt($(".num:last").text()) + 1;
                 $($("<span class='num'> " + i + " </span>")).appendTo($(".number")).closest("td").removeClass('number');
             }
             event.preventDefault();
         });

         $("#deleteField").click(function (event) {
             var lengthRow = $("#field tbody tr").length;
             if (lengthRow > 1)
                 $("#field tbody tr:last").remove();
             event.preventDefault();
         });
     });

     function filldd() {
         var data = [
    { id: '0', name: 'test 0' },
    { id: '1', name: 'test 1' },
    { id: '2', name: 'test 2' },
    { id: '3', name: 'test 3' },
    { id: '4', name: 'test 4' },
];

         for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             $(".myDropDownLisTId").last().append(
            $('<option />', {
                'value': data[i].id,
                'name': data[i].name,
                'text': data[i].name
            })
         );
         }
     }

    </script>
```

Comment: So you want to add datepicker to each row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

**HTML**

```
<table id="field">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Alternatif <span class='num'>1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="myDropDownLisTId"> <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></select></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteField">Delete Field</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
             filldd();
             CreateDP();
            var rowstring = "<tr><td class='number'>Alternatif</td><td><input type='text'/></td><td><select class='myDropDownLisTId'/><input type='text' class='datepicker'/></td></tr>";
             $("#addField").click(function (event) {
             $("#field tbody").append(rowstring);
             filldd();
             CreateDP();
             if ($("td").hasClass("number")) {
                 var i = parseInt($(".num:last").text()) + 1;
                 $($("<span class='num'> " + i + " </span>")).appendTo($(".number")).closest("td").removeClass('number');
             }
             event.preventDefault();
         });

         $("#deleteField").click(function (event) {
             var lengthRow = $("#field tbody tr").length;
             if (lengthRow > 1)
                 $("#field tbody tr:last").remove();
             event.preventDefault();
         });     
});

 function filldd(){
    var data = [
    { id: '0', name: 'test 0' },
    { id: '1', name: 'test 1' },
    { id: '2', name: 'test 2' },
    { id: '3', name: 'test 3' },
    { id: '4', name: 'test 4' },
];

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         $(".myDropDownLisTId").last().append(
            $('<option />', {
                'value': data[i].id,
                'name': data[i].name,
                'text': data[i].name
            })
         );
     }
         }

         function CreateDP(){
             $(".datepicker").last().datepicker();
         }
```

**[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/4/)**

Comment: It most certainly does. Thank you. I am will be asking more questions related to this.

Comment: btw i want to change the look of date picker

Comment: nevermind the look, can you tell me how i can add id to the textbox and dropdown? just like you did for calendar control. Because I am not sure how i am gonna validate and save the values entered in these fields if they dont have unique ids

Comment: You can genearte dynamic Ids for each row. and use those id's in your code.

Comment: oh you mean using the first column srno for finding controls ? Yeah I think that would be sufficient right?

Comment: suppose I want to get the value of datepicker of 3rd row.. how can i do so?

Comment: Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/5/. In this fiddle each row has dynamic id. so if you want to fetch datepicker of third row than select the row3 and get it's child element with id as datepicker.

Comment: I do not want to trouble you but I just noticed that this is not working in Internet explorer. I mean I am not able to generate rows in internet explorer with our code.

Comment: I tried it on IE8.. any idea what might be wrong and how can we fix this?

Comment: It might be the issue of jquery's latest version. Please try using the  older version or try using migration plugin of jquery

Comment: fixed it.. changed  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  to  for (i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++)